# Why DTBO fails on load and says no symbols in root of device tree.?

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-tree

I am trying to build a DTBO from a dts file.
I have a few questions here.

I get a warning when I build this -

```
/opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/dtc -o dtb -o phyDriver.dtbo -@ ./phyDriver.dts   

 (avoid_unnecessary_addr_size): /fragment@1/__overlay__: unnecessary #address-cells/#size-cells without "ranges" or child "reg" property
```

Here is my phyDriver.dts file from which I have generated the dtbo file.

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    fragment@1 {
        target = <&phy0>;
        __overlay__ {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            custom_port_phy {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;
                compatible = "custom,custom-port-phy";
                Dummy_Port_Phy0: dummy_port_phy@0 {
                    reg = <0>;
                    speed = <1000>;
                };
                Dummy_Port_Phy1: dummy_port_phy@1 {
                    reg = <1>;
                    speed = <1000>;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};

OF: resolver: no symbols in root of device tree.
OF: resolver: overlay phandle fixup failed: -22
create_overlay: Failed to create overlay (err=-22)
```

Here is my dts file. I am not sure what should be the target value. But, I think the problem is with the target. Here is my root dts file. I see that I have a phy0 entry in my root dts file. Is there anything
I can do to surpass this. My aim is to be able to insert this DTBO so that my phy driver works. 
I don't care what target value is.

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    #address-cells = <0x1>;
    #size-cells = <0x1>;
    compatible = "avnet,zynq-microzed", "xlnx,zynq-microzed", "xlnx,zynq-7000";
    model = "Avnet MicroZed board";

    cpus {
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x0>;

        cpu@0 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9";
            device_type = "cpu";
            reg = <0x0>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x3>;
            clock-latency = <0x3e8>;
            cpu0-supply = <0x2>;
            operating-points = <0xa2c2b 0xf4240 0x51616 0xf4240>;
        };

        cpu@1 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9";
            device_type = "cpu";
            reg = <0x1>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x3>;
        };
    };

    fpga-full {
        compatible = "fpga-region";
        fpga-mgr = <0x3>;
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;
        ranges;
    };

    pmu@f8891000 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-pmu";
        interrupts = <0x0 0x5 0x4 0x0 0x6 0x4>;
        interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
        reg = <0xf8891000 0x1000 0xf8893000 0x1000>;
    };

    fixedregulator {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        regulator-name = "VCCPINT";
        regulator-min-microvolt = <0xf4240>;
        regulator-max-microvolt = <0xf4240>;
        regulator-boot-on;
        regulator-always-on;
        phandle = <0x2>;
    };

    amba {
        u-boot,dm-pre-reloc;
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;
        interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
        ranges;

        adc@f8007100 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-xadc-1.00.a";
            reg = <0xf8007100 0x20>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x7 0x4>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0xc>;
        };

        can@e0008000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-can-1.0";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x13 0x1 0x24>;
            clock-names = "can_clk", "pclk";
            reg = <0xe0008000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x1c 0x4>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            tx-fifo-depth = <0x40>;
            rx-fifo-depth = <0x40>;
        };

        can@e0009000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-can-1.0";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x14 0x1 0x25>;
            clock-names = "can_clk", "pclk";
            reg = <0xe0009000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x33 0x4>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            tx-fifo-depth = <0x40>;
            rx-fifo-depth = <0x40>;
        };

        gpio@e000a000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-gpio-1.0";
            #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x2a>;
            gpio-controller;
            interrupt-controller;
            #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x14 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe000a000 0x1000>;
        };

        i2c@e0004000 {
            compatible = "cdns,i2c-r1p10";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x26>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x19 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0004000 0x1000>;
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
        };

        i2c@e0005000 {
            compatible = "cdns,i2c-r1p10";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x27>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x30 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0005000 0x1000>;
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
        };

        interrupt-controller@f8f01000 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-gic";
            #interrupt-cells = <0x3>;
            interrupt-controller;
            reg = <0xf8f01000 0x1000 0xf8f00100 0x100>;
            phandle = <0x4>;
        };

        cache-controller@f8f02000 {
            compatible = "arm,pl310-cache";
            reg = <0xf8f02000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x2 0x4>;
            arm,data-latency = <0x3 0x2 0x2>;
            arm,tag-latency = <0x2 0x2 0x2>;
            cache-unified;
            cache-level = <0x2>;
        };

        memory-controller@f8006000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-ddrc-a05";
            reg = <0xf8006000 0x1000>;
        };

        ocmc@f800c000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-ocmc-1.0";
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x3 0x4>;
            reg = <0xf800c000 0x1000>;
        };

        serial@e0000000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,xuartps", "cdns,uart-r1p8";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x17 0x1 0x28>;
            clock-names = "uart_clk", "pclk";
            reg = <0xe0000000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x1b 0x4>;
        };

        serial@e0001000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,xuartps", "cdns,uart-r1p8";
            status = "okay";
            clocks = <0x1 0x18 0x1 0x29>;
            clock-names = "uart_clk", "pclk";
            reg = <0xe0001000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x32 0x4>;
        };

        spi@e0006000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-spi-r1p6";
            reg = <0xe0006000 0x1000>;
            status = "disabled";
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x1a 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x19 0x1 0x22>;
            clock-names = "ref_clk", "pclk";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
        };

        spi@e0007000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-spi-r1p6";
            reg = <0xe0007000 0x1000>;
            status = "disabled";
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x31 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x1a 0x1 0x23>;
            clock-names = "ref_clk", "pclk";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
        };

        spi@e000d000 {
            clock-names = "ref_clk", "pclk";
            clocks = <0x1 0xa 0x1 0x2b>;
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-qspi-1.0";
            status = "disabled";
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x13 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe000d000 0x1000>;
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
        };

        memory-controller@e000e000 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            status = "disabled";
            clock-names = "memclk", "apb_pclk";
            clocks = <0x1 0xb 0x1 0x2c>;
            compatible = "arm,pl353-smc-r2p1", "arm,primecell";
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x12 0x4>;
            ranges;
            reg = <0xe000e000 0x1000>;

            flash@e1000000 {
                status = "disabled";
                compatible = "arm,pl353-nand-r2p1";
                reg = <0xe1000000 0x1000000>;
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x1>;
            };

            flash@e2000000 {
                status = "disabled";
                compatible = "cfi-flash";
                reg = <0xe2000000 0x2000000>;
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x1>;
            };
        };

        ethernet@e000b000 {
            compatible = "cdns,zynq-gem", "cdns,gem";
            reg = <0xe000b000 0x1000>;
            status = "okay";
            interrupts = <0x0 0x16 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x1e 0x1 0x1e 0x1 0xd>;
            clock-names = "pclk", "hclk", "tx_clk";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            phy-mode = "rgmii-id";
            phy-handle = <0x5>;

            ethernet-phy@0 {
                reg = <0x0>;
                phandle = <0x5>;
            };
        };

        ethernet@e000c000 {
            compatible = "cdns,zynq-gem", "cdns,gem";
            reg = <0xe000c000 0x1000>;
            status = "disabled";
            interrupts = <0x0 0x2d 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x1f 0x1 0x1f 0x1 0xe>;
            clock-names = "pclk", "hclk", "tx_clk";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
        };

        mmc@e0100000 {
            compatible = "arasan,sdhci-8.9a";
            status = "okay";
            clock-names = "clk_xin", "clk_ahb";
            clocks = <0x1 0x15 0x1 0x20>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x18 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0100000 0x1000>;
        };

        mmc@e0101000 {
            compatible = "arasan,sdhci-8.9a";
            status = "disabled";
            clock-names = "clk_xin", "clk_ahb";
            clocks = <0x1 0x16 0x1 0x21>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x2f 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0101000 0x1000>;
        };

        slcr@f8000000 {
            u-boot,dm-pre-reloc;
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-slcr", "syscon", "simple-mfd";
            reg = <0xf8000000 0x1000>;
            ranges;
            phandle = <0x6>;

            clkc@100 {
                u-boot,dm-pre-reloc;
                #clock-cells = <0x1>;
                compatible = "xlnx,ps7-clkc";
                fclk-enable = <0xf>;
                clock-output-names = "armpll", "ddrpll", "iopll", "cpu_6or4x", "cpu_3or2x", "cpu_2x", "cpu_1x", "ddr2x", "ddr3x", "dci", "lqspi", "smc", "pcap", "gem0", "gem1", "fclk0", "fclk1", "fclk2", "fclk3", "can0", "can1", "sdio0", "sdio1", "uart0", "uart1", "spi0", "spi1", "dma", "usb0_aper", "usb1_aper", "gem0_aper", "gem1_aper", "sdio0_aper", "sdio1_aper", "spi0_aper", "spi1_aper", "can0_aper", "can1_aper", "i2c0_aper", "i2c1_aper", "uart0_aper", "uart1_aper", "gpio_aper", "lqspi_aper", "smc_aper", "swdt", "dbg_trc", "dbg_apb";
                reg = <0x100 0x100>;
                ps-clk-frequency = <0x1fca055>;
                phandle = <0x1>;
            };

            rstc@200 {
                compatible = "xlnx,zynq-reset";
                reg = <0x200 0x48>;
                #reset-cells = <0x1>;
                syscon = <0x6>;
            };

            pinctrl@700 {
                compatible = "xlnx,pinctrl-zynq";
                reg = <0x700 0x200>;
                syscon = <0x6>;

                usb0-default {
                    phandle = <0x8>;

                    mux {
                        groups = "usb0_0_grp";
                        function = "usb0";
                    };

                    conf {
                        groups = "usb0_0_grp";
                        slew-rate = <0x0>;
                        io-standard = <0x1>;
                    };

                    conf-rx {
                        pins = "MIO29", "MIO31", "MIO36";
                        bias-high-impedance;
                    };

                    conf-tx {
                        pins = "MIO28", "MIO30", "MIO32", "MIO33", "MIO34", "MIO35", "MIO37", "MIO38", "MIO39";
                        bias-disable;
                    };
                };
            };
        };

        dmac@f8003000 {
            compatible = "arm,pl330", "arm,primecell";
            reg = <0xf8003000 0x1000>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupt-names = "abort", "dma0", "dma1", "dma2", "dma3", "dma4", "dma5", "dma6", "dma7";
            interrupts = <0x0 0xd 0x4 0x0 0xe 0x4 0x0 0xf 0x4 0x0 0x10 0x4 0x0 0x11 0x4 0x0 0x28 0x4 0x0 0x29 0x4 0x0 0x2a 0x4 0x0 0x2b 0x4>;
            #dma-cells = <0x1>;
            #dma-channels = <0x8>;
            #dma-requests = <0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x1b>;
            clock-names = "apb_pclk";
        };

        devcfg@f8007000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-devcfg-1.0";
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x8 0x4>;
            reg = <0xf8007000 0x100>;
            clocks = <0x1 0xc 0x1 0xf 0x1 0x10 0x1 0x11 0x1 0x12>;
            clock-names = "ref_clk", "fclk0", "fclk1", "fclk2", "fclk3";
            syscon = <0x6>;
            phandle = <0x3>;
        };

        efuse@f800d000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-efuse";
            reg = <0xf800d000 0x20>;
        };

        timer@f8f00200 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-global-timer";
            reg = <0xf8f00200 0x20>;
            interrupts = <0x1 0xb 0x301>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x4>;
        };

        timer@f8001000 {
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0xa 0x4 0x0 0xb 0x4 0x0 0xc 0x4>;
            compatible = "cdns,ttc";
            clocks = <0x1 0x6>;
            reg = <0xf8001000 0x1000>;
        };

        timer@f8002000 {
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x25 0x4 0x0 0x26 0x4 0x0 0x27 0x4>;
            compatible = "cdns,ttc";
            clocks = <0x1 0x6>;
            reg = <0xf8002000 0x1000>;
        };

        timer@f8f00600 {
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x1 0xd 0x301>;
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-twd-timer";
            reg = <0xf8f00600 0x20>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x4>;
        };

        usb@e0002000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-usb-2.20a", "chipidea,usb2";
            status = "okay";
            clocks = <0x1 0x1c>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x15 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0002000 0x1000>;
            phy_type = "ulpi";
            dr_mode = "host";
            usb-phy = <0x7>;
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <0x8>;
        };

        usb@e0003000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-usb-2.20a", "chipidea,usb2";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x1d>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x2c 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0003000 0x1000>;
            phy_type = "ulpi";
        };

        watchdog@f8005000 {
            clocks = <0x1 0x2d>;
            compatible = "cdns,wdt-r1p2";
            interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x9 0x1>;
            reg = <0xf8005000 0x1000>;
            timeout-sec = <0xa>;
        };
    };

    aliases {
        ethernet0 = "/amba/ethernet@e000b000";
        serial0 = "/amba/serial@e0001000";
    };

    memory@0 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x0 0x40000000>;
    };

    chosen {
        bootargs = "earlycon";
        stdout-path = "serial0:115200n8";
    };

    phy0 {
        compatible = "usb-nop-xceiv";
        #phy-cells = <0x0>;
        phandle = <0x7>;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1: unnecessary #address-cells/#size-cells without "ranges" or child "reg" property**

Your `__overlay__` node has `#address-cells` and `#size-cells`, this means you should have a `reg` property in its subnodes (i.e. `custom_port_phy`) that set the address and size (or use the `ranges` property).

Since you need no addressing of subnodes, just remove `#address-cells` and `#size-cells` from `__overlay__`.

On the other hand, the `#address-cells` and `#size-cells` in the `custom_port_phy` are correct, because its subnodes (`dummy_port_phy@0` and `dummy_port_phy@1`) do have a `reg` property.

The result should be:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    fragment@1 {
        target = <&phy0>;
        __overlay__ {

         // Remove these (custom_port_phy has no reg)
         // #address-cells = <0x1>;
         // #size-cells = <0x1>;

            custom_port_phy {

                // Leave these (dummy_port_phy@X have reg)
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;

                compatible = "custom,custom-port-phy";
                Dummy_Port_Phy0: dummy_port_phy@0 {
                    reg = <0>;
                    speed = <1000>;
                };
                Dummy_Port_Phy1: dummy_port_phy@1 {
                    reg = <1>;
                    speed = <1000>;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

**Problem 2: no symbols in root of device tree**

You need to compile the base device tree with the `-@` flag. This way the base tree will expose its `__symbols__` (including the `phy0` you need) and it will be found when applying the overlay.

See [the kernel code that emits that error](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6-rc7/source/drivers/of/resolver.c#L309).

Comment: But, I can see that my subnode has reg property.  reg = <0>; Since the reg property has just address and no size. I have set the address-cells to 1 and size-cells to 0. This is just like a CPU address.

Comment: Only your `dummy_port_phy@X` have `reg`, so only their parent node (`custom_port_phy`) must have `#address-cells` and `#size-cells`. You have to remove the `#address-cells` and `#size-cells` only from the `__overlay__` node. -- I just added i the answer your initial code fixed, it should be clear now.